# Strange behaviour of TableForm

Tags: list-manipulation

```
tab = {
   {0.9420076, 0.9979831},
   {0.6985363, 0.9860302},
   {0.3964154, 0.9523944},
   {0.4683808, 0.9640774},
   {0.3644067, 0.9458417},
   {0.2378723, 0.9048291},
   {0.2726637, 0.9194800},
   {0.1667687, 0.8590895}
   };
TableForm[tab]
```

When put into `TableForm`, the 7th decimal place got chopped off, leaving the ugly "left-aligned" column, which looks like some digits missing. How could I ask it to leave as it is?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SetPrecision[tab, 7] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the PrintPrecision. This works on V 10.01, windows 7

```
tab = {{0.9420076, 0.9979831}, {0.6985363, 0.9860302}, {0.3964154, 0.9523944}, 
   {0.4683808, 0.9640774}, {0.3644067,  0.9458417}, {0.2378723, 0.9048291}, 
   {0.2726637, 0.9194800}, {0.1667687, 0.8590895}};
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision ->7]
TableForm[tab]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Well, check the second to last one in the right column. It's still ragged.